# How I can make my website fully responsive for every single device?

Tags: responsive-design

I have tried everything. I have used **Media Queries** but couldn't make [my website](https://db-smartstudy.000webhostapp.com/) responsive.

Comment: Please be specific and share what you have tried so far.

Comment: And add your code etc. into your question, not asking people to debug your website.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.